# I need help moving info from one column into another column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
0071    3/4-1
0072    1.5-3
0072    1-3
0072    1.5-1
0072    1-1
```

Above are part numbers located in Column A and Column B of an Excel spreadsheet.  I am trying to combine the columns.  Basically, the entire part number of row 1 is actually `0071 3/4-1`.  Unfortunately, it was entered into two columns instead of 1 so that 0071 is in Column A and 3/4-1 is in Column B.  This is the case for several hundred part numbers in this spreadsheet.  As stated, I want to move the info in Column B over to Column A.  Furthermore, I need a single space between the numbers: `00713/4-1` won't work.  It has to be `0071 3/4-1`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks everyone.  You have just made my life much easier!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Insert an extra column (C is easiest), fill the top row with `=A1&" "&B1` and copy this all the way down.
2. Select that column, copy it.
3. Select column A, now select `Paste Special`, then `Values`, so that the actual *values* are copied from C to A (and not the *formulas*).
4. Delete column C.
5. Delete column B if you no longer need it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you have a first part in `A15` and the second part in `B15`.
You can get the whole string in any other cell by using [this formula](http://www.mrexcel.com/tip074.shtml):

```
=A15&" "&B15
```

Alternative you can use:

```
=CONCATENATE(A15," ",B15)
```